# HttpPost Async retunrs BadRequest from hosted application c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpclient

I am calling a JVA RESTful API from my c# code and passing a data type "MultipartFormDataContent" as one of the parameters.
This has an object named "attachments" and the size of it could be as big as 2GB.
All this works fine when I run the code locally from my PC.
However, when I host the code on my IIS app server it fails when the file size is >20MB. It works fine for files <20MB.
In IIS, I do have the "RequestFiltering maxAllowedContentLength set to 2147483647".

Here is the code:

```
  HttpContent messageContent = new StringContent(jss.Serialize(new
                {
                    to ="abc@xyz.com"
                    cc ="abc@xyz.com",
                    subject = "Subject",
                    body ="body"                   
                }));

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);

                    var section = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("secureAppSettings") as NameValueCollection;
                    byte[] credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(section["username"] + ":" + section["password"]);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(credentials));

                    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                    {
                        formData.Add(messageContent, "message");
                        List<Tuple<string, string, long>> listOfFiles = new List<Tuple<string, string, long>>();

                        if (Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootDocumentTemplateFileRecreatePath"] + instanceID)))
                        {
                            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootDocumentTemplateFileRecreatePath"] + instanceID));
                            //  listOfFiles.Add(new Tuple<string, string, long>(Path.GetFileName(filePaths[0]), filePaths[0], new FileInfo(filePaths[0]).Length));

                            foreach (var eachFilePath in filePaths)
                            {
                                string filename = Path.GetFileName(eachFilePath);
                                string filePath = eachFilePath;
                                long fileSize = new FileInfo(eachFilePath).Length;

                                var stream = new FileStream(eachFilePath,
                                     FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                                {

                                    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);

                                    var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream, 1024 * 1024 * 100);
                                    {
                                        var size = fileSize;
                                        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new
                                            ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachments")
                                        {
                                            FileName = filename,
                                            DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment,
                                            Name = "attachments"
                                        };
                                        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
                                        fileSizes.Add(filename, size);
                                        formData.Add(fileContent, "attachments", filename);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            fileSizesContent = new StringContent(jss.Serialize(fileSizes));
                            formData.Add(fileSizesContent, "fileSizes");
                        }

                        var response = client.PostAsync(<java RESTful service url>,formData).Result;
```

Here is the response object I get on sending files >20MB:

adRequestMethod: POST, RequestUri: 'RESTful service url', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent, Headers:
{
  Authorization: Basic TWVzc2FnZUNvdXJpZXJVc2VyOlN0YXJzTWVzc2FnZUNvdXJpZXIwMQ==
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="08c7381e-a190-4c90-98b3-a0a1dae5107b"
  Content-Length: 19998604
}Bad RequestPragma: no-cache
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache
Date: Thu, 30 Mar 2017 17:40:02 GMT

Appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sridhar

Comment: Maybe the error actually is on the java api. Try to create a API which emulates the java api behavior (a mocked version), and points your application to that. Then, you ll be able to identify if the problem is with your application or the java api.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. But if the problem was with the API I should face the same issue when I run the code locally as well right? This issue occurs only when I host my application on the server. If I consume the same API from my application which runs locally on my PC, it works fine.